# Is it possible to display related tables information (1-M relationships) on the layout while using data driven pages?

Tags: data-driven-pages, dynamic-text, map-book, esri-production-mapping

I'm using data driven pages to generate a report for every point that I have (each point represents a store) and I have used Dynamic Text to display the tabular information of these points like store name and size... but I have some information in a table related to this feature by 1-M relationships like names of employees in each store and their ages.

So how can I display the related table information on the layout and make it dynamic so that when I change the page using the data-driven page the info will change also. does Production Mapping extension helps in this case and how?

Answer (score 1):

Esri response to this :

Unfortunately, dynamic text does not support table relates.  Currently, the only way to include dynamic related data in a map series is by writing code (Python).  I don't believe that Production Mapping has an out-of-the-box solution for this. This limitation is something that the Layout Team is aware of and hopefully, something that we can address in a future release. I recommend getting this onto the ideas sight - ArcGIS Ideas - to gather traction.

and someone suggested this as an alternative solution:

https://community.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2015/02/07/creating-labels-with-related-table-data